# "Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

Path of the dlls are in the Path system environment variable.
It works in a C# windows console application and not in IIS 7.5

If I use dependency walker, it complains about some of the DLLS but how does it work in the console application and not in IIS 7.5

Comment: You need to give some examples of **what** DLL's you are having problems with.

Comment: Have you tried logging with Fuslogvw? It logs binding failures and gives you a list of exactly where it looks for dlls because the path is not necessarily being checked at all. For .NET dlls it's the GAC and the local bin that are checked usually.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Arran said you need to let us know what assembly or assemblies that are throwing the exception.

Since this is an MVC3 project did you make sure to add your deployable dependencies that MVC 3 requires before publishing?

See this article if you haven't [Bin Deploy ASP.NET MVC3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)